# I use audioplayers package but i don't hear any thing

Tags: flutter-audioplayers

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          var player = AudioPlayer();
          player.play(AssetSource("black.wav"));
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            width: 60,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: const Center(
              child: Text(
                "play",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This appears in DEBUG CONSOLE:

```
V/MediaPlayer( 5512): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer( 5512): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
```